# Bundle loses its values between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, android-bundle

I use the following codes to start activity with bundle extras data, and I can see the data has saved in Intent extras:

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, AccountItem account, TransactionItem transaction) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("arg_key_account", account);
    args.putParcelable("arg_key_transaction", transaction);
    args.putInt("test_key", 18);

    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, TransactionConnectActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("arg_key", args);
    intent.putExtra("test_key", 21);
    return intent;
}
```

[image]

However, when I try to get bundle extras data from intent, the bundle has no data:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        int test = intent.getIntExtra("test_key", -1);
        Bundle args = intent.getExtras().getBundle("arg_key");
    }
    ...
}
```

[image]

The custom object have implement `Parcelable`, and all members have been written to parcel. and I have read these questions and answers, but still cannot figure out where i am wrong?

- [Pendingintent getbroadcast lost parcelable data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478422/pendingintent-getbroadcast-lost-parcelable-data)
- [Parcelable object that receives passed data coming up null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157268/parcelable-object-that-receives-passed-data-coming-up-null)
- [Parcelable custom object losing instance values when passed with intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701519/parcelable-custom-object-losing-instance-values-when-passed-with-intent)
- [Bundle loses values between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751627/bundle-loses-values-between-activities)

Comment: Too careless, I use `writeValue` to parcel a String member, which must use `writeString`.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. Or just delete the question if it has no value. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure `Parcelable` works, should use correct method to `writeToParcel` and `createFromParcel`, otherwise Android cannot retrieve data correctly which will cause `createFromParcel` returns a null object.

As for this issue here, I use `writeValue` to parcel a String member, which must use `writeString`.